# Font weight changes after navigating to page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I am seeing an issue on my ASP MVC site where after navigating to the page, it seems that a different font weight is being set after about 1-2 seconds.

For example, my `h1` title looks like this immediately after navigating to the page:

[image]

But about a second later, it looks like this:

[image]

What I don't understand here, is that I **don't** see this problem when just using the default font in bootstrap (`helvetica neue`).

However, as soon as I try using the [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) font, then I get this issue, which I use by including this in my `<head>`:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
```

And this in my style sheet:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

I don't have any other code which affects font-weight or font-size (apart from what exists in the default bootstrap styles).

What is going on here? Is this some issue with the font itself?

### UPDATE

I was able to parrtially resolve this by overring the bootstrap.css `font-weight` rules with, for example:

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
.jumbotron p {
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

However, I still see the issue for tags such as `<strong>`, where the default bootstrap is:

```
b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

So I can also override that as above, but then I lose the ability to have `<strong>` tags, and in fact lose the ability to have different `font-weights` for different tags altogether, which is of course not ideal.

Comment: Are you sure that your bootstrap don't affect the  `<h> ` or the  `<strong> `. Why didn't you trued the @import url('') methode in css? Instead of ading in the head tag?

Comment: @Steven Bootstrap does affect those tags, but I want to override those styles. I now realise that in the linked styleshee for the font it has the line `font-weight: 400`, but even after adding these styles manually and removing those lines, I still see the issue. Surely my only option isn't to manually change every single `font-weight` in `bootstrap.css`?

Comment: Yes I think the only option you have is to manually override. I did something to. And now I noticed that bootstrap also override my font-weight. I never noticed that

Comment: Surely it's bad practice to change these values in `bootstrap.css` though... Shouldn't my stylesheet just override the `font-weight`s without showing the original values?

Comment: No because in my example he override `<label>` because that is more specified then `<body>`. You can say in your css style `body label{ font-weight: 400; }` instead of changing the `bootstrap.css`

Comment: I think when you enter the page, Roboto font was not loaded. After some seconds, it was loaded successfuly and apply to your HTML. So you can see the change.

Comment: @Duannx I am pretty sure the problemis with font-weigt, as the font does not change, and after playing with the font-weight values I am seeing SOME success, however I still don't have a full solution for this

Comment: Hmm.. Can you show your HTML and CSS

Comment: @Duannx All relevant code is in my question, apart from the default bootstrap css, which you can find online. I also tried replacing my `<head>` font call with `@import` as Steven suggested, but with the same results. The problem is definitely with `font-weight`, as I mentioned above, if I explicitly set the `font-weight` to each individual text item in my custom css file, the issue is resolved. However, this prevents me from applying `bold` or other font-weights to any other text areas without seeing the original issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that I was importing this stylesheet:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext');
```

Where actually, I want something more along the lines of :

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext');
```

Which should include all the `font-weight`s I might need.

I found this by playing around with the `customize` option after choosing the font [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto&selection.subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext)